# Msgbox yes or no always delete all changes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have button on my form that should exit the form. When this button is clicked, a message box prompts you to "save changes?" with a yes or no. Unfortunately, regardless of whether 'yes' or 'no' is clicked the code below does not save changes:

```
Private Sub Prekid_Click()

    If Me.Dirty Then If MsgBox("Da li želite da saèuvate promene?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Upisivanje_Click

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo

    Forms!Pregled!LicencaList.Form.Requery
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the `Upisivanje_Click` sub.

Comment: its only DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord, the problem is because DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo delete everything, i only need to use it when answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `If ... Then ...` in a single line can be confusing, as you have just demonstrated. :)

You code should be:

```
Private Sub Prekid_Click()

    If Me.Dirty Then
        If MsgBox("Da li želite da saèuvate promene?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Call Upisivanje_Click
        Else    ' No case
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
        End If
    End If

    Forms!Pregled!LicencaList.Form.Requery
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

`acCmdUndo` should only run in the Else case (if `No` was clicked).

Comment: thanks, i tried something similar but it did not work